# Error with htmlagilitypack when When I come to htmldocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

error with html agility pack, when I debug the code and get to: where htmldoc = new HTML Document ();
so would it find a file HtmlDocument.cs
Is this a bug and how can I fix it?

```
string Url = "http://www.mittanbud.no/bedriftsok/?q=Baderom";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionReadEncoding = false;
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: This, I get that wrong : http://postimage.org/image/62rw2m8g1/

Comment: The image you post is useless. Please post a full exception stackframe. I personally have no error with the code you posted, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
```

Comment: Now I get the same error but with the htmlweb.cs instead as it looks for

Answer (score 0):

Maybe binaries, linked to your project, are built with another version of sources. Try rebuild htmlagilitypack.